# How to get span value jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get spans text by passing the value of span id to the function like this :

```
function getDetails(testDetailId){
alert(jq("#"+testDetailId).text());
}
```

And I always get null alerted when the click is invoked :

```
jq("table tr").click(function(){
var testDetailId = jq(this).attr("id");
getDetails(testDetailId);
});
```

I use jquery no conflict :

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
```

some html :

```
<span id="2">[{"testId":22,"testPerfReports":[]}]</span>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: It would help to see your mark-up.

Comment: Your code is a bit strange... why do you have this extra `getDetails` function? You already have a reference to the element, `this`, so you could just do `jq(this).text()` inside the event handler (if this is what you want, which I doubt somehow, but that is the same as what you are doing).

Comment: As an aside, 2 is an invalid id name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @Felix Kling span is not in the table at all, if that is what you're refering to

Comment: @ScottE good catch I'll try to alter the code add a letter before

Comment: @London: Then I assume that your `tr` element either has no ID or you have two elements with the same ID, which is invalid. Otherwise your code does not make sense. Please create a  http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @ScottE: IDs starting with numbers are allowed in HTML5.

Comment: @Felix Kling I checked that the tr id is valid value, at least in firebug

Comment: Then both the `tr` element and the `span` have the same id? That could be the problem. As I said, IDs have to be unique. Please create a  http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: @Felix Kling God you're smart, yes believe me I know about the one id rule, but working late really got me nowhere. that was it, please answer I'll accept

Comment: @London: No worries, for others it is not late yet and can jump in to help you ;)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that both,  the `tr` element and the `span` have the same ID.

That could be the problem, IDs have to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are capturing the click event of the `<TR>`. As they are part of a table they do not have the `text()` function. If you are trying to get the text of the span try doing the following:

```
jq("table tr").click(function(){
    var concatenatedValues = $.map($('jq(this).find('span').text(), function (text) {
                return option.value;
            }).join(',');

    alert(concatenatedValues);
});
```